# I want to copy my in file on to my out file.

Tags: c

In this code I opened my files in my open_file function. Then the process_file function needs to copy the text from my in file and Copy it to an out file. Right now it produces a new file but it is blank. It does not give me any error messages. I do not know what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

FILE* open_file(char prompt[], char mode[]);
FILE* process_file(FILE* in, FILE* out);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE* in = NULL;
    FILE* out = NULL;

    printf("MAD-LIBS Text Processor\n");
    printf("The Program will open a mad-libs file, ask you to fill various words, and produce a funny story.\n");

    open_file("Enter mad-lib file name:\n", "r");
    open_file("Enter file name for resulting story:\n", "w");
    process_file(in, out);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
/* open_file = prompts user for file name & and attempts to open it, if it fails it prompts the user again. */
FILE* open_file(char prompt [], char mode[]) {
    char filename[255];
    FILE* in;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        scanf("%s", filename);

        in = fopen(filename, mode);

        if (in == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to open file: %s. Try Again!\n", filename);
        }
    } while(in == NULL);
    return in;
}
/* process_file = processes entire input file and writes it to output file */
FILE* process_file(FILE* in, FILE* out) {
    char content[MAX_LEN];
    char NewContent[MAX_LEN];
    //gets whats in file in
    while(fgets(content, content[MAX_LEN], in) != NULL) {
        fputs (content, stdout);
        strcat(NewContent, content);
    }
    // copies it 
    while (fgets(content, content[MAX_LEN], in) != NULL) {
        fprintf(out, "%s", content);
    }
    printf("Successfully copied file\n");
    return in;
}
```

Comment: In addition to Pablo's answer below, be aware you can gain significant copy performance on Linux using `sendfile` which performs the I/O in kernel space with a significant performance edge. You can also `mmap` the file as well.

Comment: I'm surprised that no warnings are issued when the 'process_file(in, out);' call is made with uninitialized values;(

Answer (score 1):

You never assign the `FILE*` from `open_file` function to your variable, so it never gets processed.

```
in = open_file("Enter mad-lib file name:\n", "r");
out = open_file("Enter file name for resulting story:\n", "w");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the `FILE` pointers that `open_file` is returning, so `in`
and `out` remain uninitialized.

You have to do:

```
in = open_file("Enter mad-lib file name:\n", "r");
out = open_file("Enter file name for resulting story:\n", "w");
process_file(in, out);
```

Also your `process_file` is wrong. `NewContent` is not initialized, when you do

```
strcat(NewContent, content);
```

this yields undefined behaviour. Declare `NewContent` like this:

```
char NewContent[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
```

so that it is properly `\0`-terminated.

Also depending on the size of the file you are copying, `MAX_LEN` might not be
long enough to hold the whole file. In that case you would overflow the buffer.
It would be better not to use `NewContent` in the first place and write to `out`
in the same reading loop:

```
FILE* process_file(FILE* in, FILE* out) {
    char content[MAX_LEN];
    //gets whats in file in
    while(fgets(content, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL) { //<- your fgets was wrong
        fputs (content, stdout);
        fprintf(out, "%s", content); // or fputs(content, out);
    }
    printf("Successfully copied file\n");
    return in;
}
```

And you were calling `fgets` incorrectly (look at my corrected code)

Also bear in mind, that you did have 2 loop doing `while(fgets(...) != NULL`.
Well, the first loop ends, that's because `fgets` returns `NULL`, most likely
because the whole file was read or there was an I/O error. In either case
subsequent calls of `fgets` will return `NULL` as well, so your second loop
would not even be executed at all.

Comment: You got something against `fputs (content, out);`? (or are you just so used to `fprintf` it is automatic `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the `fprintf` comes out of habit and because I didn't want to look up, whether `fputs` also writes a newline as `puts` does.

Comment: I knew it `:)` -- `fputs` don't so you would be safe. It's really handy both for `stdout` and `out` in this case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, I ended up reading the man page again and from what I see, only `puts` writes an addition newline (kind of inconsistent from the standard in my opinion). I've edited my answer to include `fputs(contents, out)` (although only as commented line) :)

Comment: Correct. Either way is fine, I was just playing with you a bit. Good answer as usual.